# When is offset committed in KafkaListener.java in Springboot?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

There are two parts to my question.

1. In below Springboot KafkaListener implementation when does offset get committed for offset strategy `auto-offset-reset: latest` and `enable-auto-commit: true`? Is it immediately after the message is received by the consumer or after the whole method implementing the KafkaListener has completed?

KafkaConsumer.java

```
@KafkaListener(topics = "${spring.kafka.consumer.topic}")
    public ResponseEntity<String> consume(String message) {
        log.info("Message recieved from Kafka topic {}", message); // offset committed HERE?
        KafkaResponse kafkaResponse = new Gson().fromJson(message, KafkaResponse.class);
        myBusinessService.processKafkaResponse(kafkaResponse);
        return new ResponseEntity<>("Successfully Received", HttpStatus.OK);// OR offset committed HERE?
    }
```

2. In `application.yml` for the below properties which statements are True/False/what's the correct answer?:

> ```
> max-poll-records: 100
> max-poll-interval-ms: 200000
> enable-auto-commit: true 
> auto-commit-interval: 3000
> auto-offset-reset: latest
> isolation-level: READ_UNCOMMITTED
> fetch-max-bytes: 52428800
> ```

- Between `auto-offset-reset: latest` and `auto-commit-interval: 3000` if the Kafka consumer breaks down before 3 seconds then no offset would be committed for any record processed during those 3 seconds?
- Between `max-poll-interval-ms: 200000` and `auto-commit-interval: 3000` Kafka consumer would surely be polling the broker after an interval of `200000` seconds even if the consumer hasn't finished committing the current batch of offsets in `3000` seconds?
- Between the combination of `max-poll-records: 100` and `fetch-max-bytes: 52428800` which would take a priority if 99th record has exceeded 52428800 bytes?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's best not to use `enable.auto.commit=true`. Spring commits the offsets in a more deterministic fashion, either after all the records from a poll have been processed (default - `AckMode.BATCH`) or after each record is processed `AckMode.RECORD`.

`enable.auto.commit` won't commit until the next `poll()` and then only if the the `auto.commit.interval` has passed.

Comment: Isn't the entire batch rolled back for 100 records per se when the max-poll-records=100 even if I am opting for manual commit?

Comment: No; if you are using `AckMode.MANUAL`, any successful acks called before the failure are queued up and committed before calling the error handler with the remaining records; seeks are performed for just those records. If you are using `AckMode.MANUAL_IMMEDIATE` the offsets are committed immediately, as long as you call it on the listener thread.